# What is the grouding for Commensurability?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

I understand that before Hippasus of Metapontum proved that the square root of 2 is an irrational number, it was commonly assumed that, given two line segments, it would be possible to find a third line segment whose length divides evenly into the two, i.e. commensurability.

However why did the Greeks assume commensurability? What was proof, reasonsing or evidence that made them think in this way? Or was it only an assumption without any proper justification?

Also what made Hippasus doubt this assumption? What motivated him to prove this assumption was wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have posted this question to  History of Science and Mathematics.

Comment: See [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2/irrationality-of-the-square-root-of-2)

Comment: No proof at all of "commensurability": simply grounded on an obvious "observation". The real discovery was the *proof* of incommensurability.